# hyperref Textfield inside the table cell

Tags: hyperref

I have a table cell with an input field inside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
     \hline
     \TextField[name=textfield,width=3cm,height=0.2cm,value=default]{Text} \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

1. How to create a padding between the table border and input border?
2. How to make the border of all the inputs black and thin? So I won't need to set the property bordercolor={0 0 0} for every input I create.
   [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{menubordercolor=0 0 0}% hmm wrong key
\makeatletter
\def\Fld@bordercolor{0 0 0} % this works.
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
     \hline
     \makebox(4,1){\TextField[name=textfield,width=3cm,height=0.2cm,value=default]{Text}} \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```