# Fillable PDF: radiobutton & other

Tags: graphics

I'm having hard times trying to create a fillable pdf form.

In particular, I can't find a way to implement two things:

• radio button with text on top

• fillable blank field for the "Last Comment"

This is what I did:

```
\begin{Form}[action=mailto:my_email@gmail.com?subject=…
{The submitted form},encoding=html, method=post]


\begin{tabbing}

xxxxxxxxxx: \= \kill  % This is needed for the right tab width

Field to identify the name: \> \TextField[name=name,width=5cm,charsize=8pt]
{\mbox{}} \\

Some text in which a question is posed: \> \\
\ChoiceMenu[combo, name=percorso, width=5cm, charsize=12pt, default=]{\mbox{}}
{Answer1, Answer2} \\


 Sex:    \> 
 \ChoiceMenu[radio,default=f,name=sex,charsize=14pt]{\mbox{}}{Male=m,Female=f}
 \end{tabbing}


\CheckBox[name=highschool,charsize=12pt]{High School}
\CheckBox[name=college,charsize=12pt]{College}
\CheckBox[name=university,charsize=12pt]{University} \\

\Submit{Submit}
\Reset{Clear}
\hfill ~\\



\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone who will help me!

Ciao!

Answer (score 3):

To have the radio buttons with text on top, put them in a tabular with the description on the first row and the buttons without descriptions on the second row.

To have a fillable blank field for the comment, I think you would like a big field with `multiline=true` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}[action=mailto:my_email@gmail.com?subject={The submitted form},encoding=html, method=post]
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}m{4cm}@{}m{5.1cm}@{}}
Field to identify the name: & 
% \makebox taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79958/hyperref-textfield-inside-the-table-cell
\makebox{\TextField[name=name,width=5cm,charsize=8pt, height=.5cm]{}}\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
Some text in which a question is posed:\\[1ex] 
\ChoiceMenu[combo, name=percorso, charsize=12pt, width=5cm]{}{Answer1, Answer2}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}m{.7cm}@{}*2{C{1.4cm}@{}}}
& Male & Female\\
Sex: &   
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108},default=f,name=sex,charsize=14pt,width=1em]{}{=m} &
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{108},default=f,name=sex,charsize=14pt,width=1em]{}{=f}\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\CheckBox[name=highschool,charsize=12pt]{High School}
\CheckBox[name=college,charsize=12pt]{College}
\CheckBox[name=university,charsize=12pt]{University}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
Comment:\\[1ex]
% multiline from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109709/101651
\TextField[name=comment,width=\linewidth,height=10cm,multiline=true]{}\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent\Submit{Submit}
\Reset{Clear}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670000/how-to-send-filled-out-form-to-e-mail ... sadly, it does not work for me. When I press the submit button in Chromium, nothing is hapenning.

Comment: @user1029391283091 Please ask a new question, I don't know how to help you